# Can I have compatibility issues with react and react-dom if I upgrade react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, npm-install, package.json, react-dom

I created a web app and I've been learning react as I go. I created a react app with create react app command, and I've been working with these versions of react,react-dom and react-router-dom.

```json
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
```

These last two were installed automatically, and I don't really understand how these interact, or if they do, even.

I want to upgrade react-router-dom from v5.3.4 to v6, but I don't know if by upgrading react-router-dom I will have compatibility issues with the other dependencies.

Are these dependencies compatible with each other?

As a bonus question, is there a place where I can see compatibility between different packages? I usually find this information by accident while reading StackOverflow answers to related questions in StackOverflow.

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend using version control such as Git. Then you can make these changes to test them out yourself. If it breaks, Git allows you to easily roll back to the version that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to upgrade react-router-dom from v5.3.4 to v6, but I don't know
> if by upgrading react-router-dom I will have compatibility issues with
> the other dependencies.
>
> Are these dependencies compatible with each other?

The only (*recent*) issue I'm aware of between `react`/`react-dom` and `react-router-dom` is between `react@18` and `react-router-dom` versions below v5.3.3 ***and*** the app was being rendered into a `React.StrictMode` component. You can read a bit more about this in my answer here: [Link tag inside BrowserRouter changes only the URL but doesn't render the component](/a/71833424/8690857). The problem is resolved in `react-router-dom@5.3.3` and higher.

If you are sticking to `react@17` there are no issues with `react-router-dom`, they work seamlessly without issue. If also upgrading to `react@18` and using `react-router-dom@5.3.3` or higher (*i.e. v6*) there are also no issues.

> Is there a place where I can see compatibility between different
> packages?

Nothing I'm aware of, no. I think most issues are found organically and may be filed as issues in the various repos hosting the specific packages. If you find an issue with a library/package, then that repo's issues tracker/section is likely where you want to start a search (*other than Googling the issue, which may lead to stackoverflow posts or the repo issues directly*).

Comment: Thank you! And yeah, I usually get to the answer by googling and finding someone having compatibility issues, I wish there was a centralized place to find these things.